# Effect of marital status change on study visa in Australia

Tags: passports, study

I was married to an Australian citizen and after around a year we divorced. My marital status on passport and ID card is still single as it was not updated. Now I want to apply for a study visa in Australia. The student visa application form asks for marital status as *Married, Never married/single, Divorced, Separated* and more.

[image: Picture MaritalStatus_StudyVisa Form Australia]

What should I mention there? Should I tick mark "Single/NeverMarried" (as I am single in the records and on my documents) or should I tick "Divorced"?

I don't know whether I am right or not but I think that if I mention divorced then they may refuse my visa as I was married to an Australian citizen.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Was your marriage registered in Australia, or did this happen somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Picking an untrue answer is never a good idea in Visa applications, including for the reason to ‘make it easier’.
If you are later in an interview, you will have to change your answer, or lie them in the face, aside from the fact that it is violating their laws to give false answers. I’d say you have to use ‘Divorced’, no options.